# Column of itemIds that are stored as a string in an array. Some arrays contain multiple itemIds and I want to store them in seperare row

Tags: python, dataframe, types

I have a column with entries stored as [array, type] and want to convert that into integers. I already manage to convert the `itemId` strings into integers by:

```py
for i in range(0,len(df)): 
    if len(df["itemIds"][i])<2:
        df['n'][i]=df.itemIds[i][0]
    else:
        df['n'][i] = df.itemIds[i]
```

[image]
But now I have the problem that some arrays have multiple string entries and I do not know how to create an extra row for those to store all values separate. I am trying to run this for loop:

```py
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if len(df.n[i])>1:
        df.loc[-1]=df.iloc[i]
```

but since the data is quite large it loads forever. Any advice is highly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
 'itemIds' : [10103923431, 1003052070, 935653934, [10040664250, 10076964903, 10106433820, 5551386]], 
 'other' : range(5, 9) 
})
#                                             itemIds  other
# 0                                       10103923431      5
# 1                                        1003052070      6
# 2                                         935653934      7
# 3  [10040664250, 10076964903, 10106433820, 5551386]      8
df = df.explode('itemIds', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
       itemIds  other
0  10103923431      5
1   1003052070      6
2    935653934      7
3  10040664250      8
4  10076964903      8
5  10106433820      8
6      5551386      8
```

Note that with `explode` you can just leave lists of 1 entry as a list rather than converting them into an `int` value. This will save some computation.